# Problems with asynchronous SQLite timing

Tags: sqlite, asynchronous, windows-phone-8

Forgive me for my ignorance, but I am new to asynchronous programming and I can't seem to figure this out.

I have a Windows Phone 8 application with many SQLite operations.

I have been having problems where occasionally, a value is set in the database, but it apparently isn't set in time for when it is retrieved.  But this does not happen consistently, which is why I am wondering if it is a threading issue.

I have a method for inserting records like so:

```
public async Task<string> getSetting(Settings setting)
    {
        string returnString = "";
        string setName = setting.getName();


        try
        {
            SQLiteAsyncConnection conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "newDatabase"), true);
            var query = conn.Table<ClientSettings>().Where(x => x.ID == setName);
            var result = await query.ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

            foreach (var item in result)
            {

                returnString = item.Value;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("\nERROR: " + e);

        }
        return ret;
    }
```

I also have a method for retrieving these:

```
public async Task<string> getSetting(Settings setting)
    {
        string returnString = "";
        string setName = setting.getName();


        try
        {
            SQLiteAsyncConnection conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "newDatabase"), true);
            var query = conn.Table<MySettings>().Where(x => x.ID == setName);
            var result = await query.ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

            foreach (var item in result)
            {
                returnString = item.Value;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("\nERROR: " + e);

        }
        return returnString;
    }
```

If I call it like this in the main page:

```
var insert = Constants.getData().setSetting(ExampleSetting, "userIDtest", false).Result;
string retrieving = Constants.getData().getSetting(ExampleSetting).Result;
```

It works fine, and a console print on the very next line of "retrieving" is the correct value.  However, in many other scenarios - if setSetting does not return a value but is instead void, the setting does not seem to be set in time, and getSetting does not return the value set.

Additionally, in part of the application, the user is prompted to enter some info, which is then set into the database and immediately used in an xml webservice.  This does not ever seem to be set in time, despite the code looking exactly like it does above.

Is this the correct way of doing this?  Is there a better method of setting SQLite records that ensures they are set, without locking the UI thread?

Comment: You have `getSetting` code shown twice above. I think you wanted to also show `setSetting`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `await` instead of `Task.Result`:

```
var insert = await Constants.getData().setSetting(ExampleSetting, "userIDtest", false);
string retrieving = await Constants.getData().getSetting(ExampleSetting);
```

The above code will wait for your db calls to complete, but will not block the UI. Note that this will not work in a console application - it will only work with a GUI application.

Beyond that your `getSetting` code looks fine. I cannot comment on `setSetting` since it is not shown in your question.

Answer (score 1):

> if setSetting does not return a value but is instead void

If `setSetting` returns `void`, then you have no way of knowing when the `async` operations have completed. An `async` method should *never* return `void` (unless it is an event handler).

If you don't want to return a value from an `async` method, make the method return value be a `Task`. That way you can still `await` the returned task to ensure `setSetting` is complete before moving on.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Also, your article "Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming" and your blog post "Don't Block on Async Code" were very helpful!